# argument of type 'numpy.int64' is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I have checked through the forum but cannot seem to make this work. I have  a CSV file and there are 1300 rows. One column is title ID. The ID column is a six digit number. When I try to find a particular number  using this code:

```
    df[df['ID'].map(lambda ID: "342270" in ID)]
```

I get the following on traceback.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call         last)
<ipython-input-12-dbef5920f124> in <module>()
----> 1 df[df['ID'].map(lambda ID: "342270" in ID)]

/home/noteleks/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas                /core/series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
                                                                                  2119                                                                               index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
   2120         else:
   -> 2121             mapped = map_f(values, arg)
  2122             return self._constructor(mapped,
  2123                                          index=self.index).__finalize__(self)

pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:63043)()

<ipython-input-12-dbef5920f124> in <lambda>(ID)
----> 1 df[df['ID'].map(lambda ID: "342270" in ID)]

TypeError: argument of type 'numpy.int64' is not iterable
```

Comment: try this `df[df.ID == 342270]` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need lambda function in this case:

```
df[df.ID == 342270]
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

When you use `in ID`, you are in effect iterating through `ID` and seeing if any item in it is equal to what comes before the `in`.  Did you perhaps want to use `str()` here:

```
df[df['ID'].map(lambda ID: "342270" in str(ID)]
```

or maybe you wanted to see if `ID` was the same thing as `342270`:

```
df[df['ID'].map(lambda ID: ID == 342270)]
```

Comment: Thank you I will put that in my toolbox.